# Why do I get "syntax error at end of input" when binding data with sqlx?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm looking to bind data through my SQL string:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, sqlx::FromRow)]
struct CurrencyExchangeRateBdd {
    currency_exchange_rate_id: i64,
    from_currency: String,
    to_currency: String,
    rate_date: Date,
    rate: f64,
    creation_date: OffsetDateTime,
    rate_down: Option<f64>,
    rate_up: Option<f64>,
}

async fn get_data(date: &String) -> Result<Vec<CurrencyExchangeRateBdd>, sqlx::Error> {
    let pool = PgPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(5)
        .connect("postgres")
        .await?;

    let row = sqlx::query_as!(
        CurrencyExchangeRateBdd,
        "SELECT * FROM currency_exchange_rate WHERE rate_date = ?"
    )
    .bind(date)
    .fetch_all(&pool)
    .await;

    row
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: error returned from database: syntax error at end of input
  --> src/main.rs:50:15
   |
50 |     let row = sqlx::query_as!(CurrencyExchangeRateBdd,"SELECT * FROM currency_exchange_rate WHERE rate_date = ?")
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I have tried:

```
let row = sqlx::query_as!(CurrencyExchangeRateBdd, "SELECT * FROM currency_exchange_rate WHERE rate_date = ?", date)
```

Or with a `$` or `@` rather than `?`. I have the same as [the documentation](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.5.5/sqlx/macro.query_as.html).

How I can fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried `$1` rather than just `?` or `$`? That is the syntax for parameters in Postgres prepared statements. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html#SQL-PREPARE-EXAMPLES

Comment: @justinas Thanks man it's work, the documentation look not up-to-date :D

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is:

```rust
let row = sqlx::query_as!(
    CurrencyExchangeRateBdd,
    "SELECT * FROM currency_exchange_rate WHERE rate_date = $1"
)
```

Postgres uses identifiers `$1`, `$2`, etc. to indicate parameters in a prepared statement. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html#SQL-PREPARE-EXAMPLES).

[The very first example in `sqlx`'s README](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/e33e4510fcab184f6bb655be3ba811e7f8a5b63f/README.md#quickstart) also shows proper usage of parameters with Postgres.

Comment: @kmdreko you're right, I forgot to actually change the placeholder. Thanks.